# Apache POI error when running on SIT

Tags: java, excel, spring, maven, apache-poi

I have been developing a SpringSource 3.2 project on Java 1.5. The aim of this project is to take an excel file and output into another file of our own format after parsing the data in the excel.

When running on my local developer environment (an i5, Windows 7 machine) the process runs completely fine and the result is as expected. But when I try to run it on our SIT (which is an old Windows Server 2003 SP2 x64) I get the following exception:

`2014-04-24 14:18:16:574 ERROR [main] - AbstractStep | Encountered an error executing the step
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/xmlbeans/XmlOptions
    at org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocumentPart.<clinit>(POIXMLDocumentPart.java:43)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.create(WorkbookFactory.java:62)
    at com.hsbc.gbm.dml.batch.item.file.ExcelFileItemReader.doOpen(ExcelFileItemReader.java:118)
    at org.springframework.batch.item.support.AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.open(AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.java:134)
    at org.springframework.batch.item.file.MultiResourceItemReader.read(MultiResourceItemReader.java:105)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider.doRead(SimpleChunkProvider.java:90)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider.read(SimpleChunkProvider.java:148)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider$1.doInIteration(SimpleChunkProvider.java:108)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.getNextResult(RepeatTemplate.java:367)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.executeInternal(RepeatTemplate.java:214)
.
.
.`

Does anyone have any idea on why this is happening? We use Maven & Spring to manage our dependencies btw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing at least on of the [Apache POI component dependencies](http://poi.apache.org/overview.html#components). Specifically, you're missing Apache XMLBeans, though it's possible you're missing other things too

The [Apache POI components page](http://poi.apache.org/overview.html#components) list all the POI modules, which components they contain, what their dependencies are, and what Maven artificats they can be fetched form. You're either missing one of the maven artifacts you need, or aren't correctly deploying the jars

Comment: Thanks for answering this very common question. I see now that this seems to be asked every other week, although the questions differ enough that you can't really search it up yourself. I think I'm starting to hate Spring now...it spoils you with all these automatic dependency injections, then suddenly offers no clear fix when the candy is yanked and you find that some obscure run script somewhere needs editing...

Answer (score 1):

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/xmlbeans/XmlOptions

clearly states that you not have some classes or maybe one of its dependencies and beans in your project `CLASSPATH` like: [xmlbeans-x.x.x.jar](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.xmlbeans/xmlbeans). Make sure that's present and readable.